# Limit mvn versions:display-dependency-updates to specific Java version?

Tags: java, maven

We use

```bash
mvn versions:display-dependency-updates
```

as part of our release cycle. Works as advertised. However, a lot of latest versions require a Java version higher than our current target in the `pom.xml`. Currently we manually review supported versions.

Is there a way/switch to "show updates compatible with Java version [insert version]"?

Comment: Simple answer: No there is no way to do that. Long answer: There is no such information in the pom files..because the versions plugin uses the metadata and pom file and on version base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @khmarbaise mentioned in comment there is no simple way to limit dependencies by target JDK.

Technically can be implemented using eg. https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-shared-jar/ to dicover target JDK in dependency.

We can start shuch discusion at project issues https://github.com/mojohaus/versions/issues

Now as workaround you can prepare rules to skip some of version
https://www.mojohaus.org/versions/versions-maven-plugin/version-rules.html